# OpenMP: How to specify how often a task should be executed

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I got the following problem. I got a 4-Core CPU and 2 different Tasks A and B. A has a significantly higher workload than B, however, has to be executed only once. B has a very small workload but a has to be executed several times.

```
void A(int data) {
    // do a lot
}

void B(int data) {
    // do not so much
}

int main() {

    int n = 100;

    int data_a;
    int data_b[n];

    #pragma omp ?ONCE? // run task A once
    A(data_a);
    #pragma omp ?N_TIMES? // run task B n times
    B(data_b[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I tell OpenMP to run A and B on 4-Cores in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

First, your code does not have neither a parallel section nor omp task instruction.
It depends on how you create your tasks.
A section of code can be executed once using 'single' omp instruction.
However, in your case, it is difficult to be sure what you want to do.
There is no loop, and therefore A and B would be executed once.
So please, update your example and then we will be able to correct it.